# X-Frame-Options Blocks Ajax Response From Being Displayed in iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have an javascript method that sends POST request using jquery to my own server (Java servlet). The response is an HTML page, which contains the tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-FRAME-Options" content="SameOrigin">
```

This page is then displayed in a iframe of the existing page. The jquery method is like this:

```
function ajaxCall(urlString, params){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType:'html',
        url: urlString ,
        data: params,
        success: function(msg){
            $("#A1B2C3D4E5").contents().find('html').html(msg);
        },
        failure:  function(msg) {
            $("#A1B2C3D4E5").contents().find('html').html(msg);
        }
    });
}
```

The HTML component that has the id A1B2C3D4E5 is an iframe. The problem is that the returned html page is not displayed in the iframe in Chrome. The error message it gives is that:

```
Refused to display 'about:blank' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SameOrigin'. jquery-1.7.2.min.js:32
Blocked a frame with origin "https://localhost:8443" from accessing a frame with origin "null".  The frame requesting access has a protocol of "https", the frame being accessed has a protocol of "data". Protocols must match.
```

It works fine on Firefox but not in Chrome.

By removing the meta section of:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-FRAME-Options" content="SameOrigin">
```

it works fine in Chrome as well. But for some reason I cannot remove this tag.

My question is that why this happens? Is there anyway to fix it and still keeps the meta tag?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This meta tag is used to prevent a page to be displayed inside the iframe of another web site, if "SameOrigin" is specified.

The webpage I received is from an Ajax call through POST, not from the containing webpage of the iframe. In this case, it is categorized as different origin rather than the same origin.

Therefore, a page requested through an jquery ajax call cannot be displayed inside the iframe of the hosting page if the meta tag is presented with "SameOrigin" value.